# How to use multiple URLs for one state without duplicating its children states?

Tags: angularjs, routes

After searching about this problem, I have found multiple questions that have the same concern. However, none of them gave me an appropriate answer for what I am trying to achieve.

In my application using AngularJS 1.5.8, I have a view displaying a document that can belong to a `User` or a `Project`. Either way, the view and the controller are the same. I want the state of this view to be accessible via multiple URLs. I want this to be possible because, the way I built my application, every state that has a URL starting with `/projects/{idProject}/` will display a custom navigation bar with shortcuts. But when the user is accessing his own document, he is not in a project section, so the navbar shouldn't display the specific buttons.

I had encountered the same issue earlier with another page, but I simply created two states so that two different URLs could lead to it with different parameters.

However, I don't find this solution suitable for this page for one reason : the state has children states that correspond to modals allowing for different CRUD operations. This means that I would need to duplicate the children states as well and I would end up with dix states instead of three, all identical except for the URL and the parent states.

Here's an edited sample of my code to help visualize :

```
.state('view-document', {
    parent: 'app',
    url: '/view/document/{idDocument}', // <-- This should also be accessed via /projects/{idProject}/view/document/{idDocument}
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/core/view/document/view-document.html',
            controller: 'ViewDocumentController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    }
})
.state('view-document.edit-field', {
    parent: 'view-document',
    url: '/edit-field',
    params: {
        field: null
    },
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$mdDialog', function ($stateParams, $state, $mdDialog) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/core/view/document/edit-field/view-document-edit-field-dialog.html',
            controller: 'ViewDocumentEditFieldController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                ...
            }
        }).then(function () {
            $state.go('view-document', null, {reload: false});
        }, function () {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    }]
})
.state('view-document.delete-field', {
    parent: 'view-document',
    url: '/field/{idField}/delete',
    params: {
        field: null
    },
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$mdDialog', function ($stateParams, $state, $mdDialog) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'app/core/view/document/delete-field/view-document-delete-field-dialog.html',
            controller: 'ViewDocumentDeleteFieldController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
            resolve: {
                ...
            }
        }).then(function () {
            $state.go('view-document', null, {reload: false});
        }, function () {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    }]
});
```

Any idea on how I could achieve this without duplicating what could be even more than two children states ? This question could also be : How can two different states share the same children states ?

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this, I ended up duplicating the states after all. I guess it's not that bad since they technically are different states.